# How can I pass from Terraform AWS ARNs to AWS SAML in the User Information of Google Workspace?

Tags: terraform, google-workspace, terraform-provider-gcp

I manage AWS user access from Google Workspace. I have been manually adding the necessary ARNs to users in User Information > AWS SAML.

Now we are using Terraform to create users in Google Workspace, but I cannot find in Terraform documentation how to pass these ARNs. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide TF code demonstrating the issue or what you want to achieve.